# Can I discover a Java class' declared inner classes using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

In Java, is there any way to use the JDK libraries to discover the private classes implemented within another class? Or do I need so use something like asm?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[`Class.getDeclaredClasses()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredClasses()) is the answer.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't list anonymous inner classes (javap will report them).

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're after: [`Class.getClasses()`](https://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClasses())

Comment: No it's not, `getClasses()` returns public classes only, including inherited ones.

Comment: Use the getDeclaredClasses() method from Class.

Answer (score 4):

```
package com.test;

public class A {

    public String str;

    public class B {
        private int i;
    }
}
package com.test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ReflectAB extends TestCase {
    public void testAccessToOuterClass() throws Exception {
           final A a = new A();
           final A.B b = a.new B();
           final Class[] parent = A.class.getClasses();
           assertEquals("com.test.A$B", parent[0].getName());
           assertEquals("i" , parent[0].getDeclaredFields()[0].getName());
           assertEquals("int",parent[0].getDeclaredFields()[0].getType().getName());
           //assertSame(a, a2);
        }

}
```

Comment: OP stated that they need a way to get PRIVATE inner classes.