# get the enclosing class object from anonymous inner class as function parameter

Tags: java

Not sure if I am asking a sound question. I know every inner class keeps a reference to the enclosing class object. So can I reference the enclosing class object outside that enclosing class given the anonymous inner class as function parameter?

```
class A{
    public static void foo(Thread t) {
        //here, how to get the reference of the enclosing class object of "t", 
        //i.e. the object of class B. I know, somebody might have put in a 
        //non-inner class Thread. But how can I check if "t" is really from an 
        //anonymous inner class of class B and then do something here?
    }
}
class B{
    public void bar() {
        A.foo(
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("inside bar!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471749/can-i-discover-a-java-class-declared-inner-classes-using-reflection

Comment: Do you need the class only or the actual instance of the enclosing class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For getting the enclosing class of `t` try `t.getClass().getEnclosingClass()`. Note that this would return `null` if there was no enclosing class.

Getting the correct instance of the enclosing class is not that easy, since this would rely on some 
undocumented implementation details (namely the `this$0` variable). Here's some more information: [In Java, how do I access the outer class when I'm not in the inner class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763543/in-java-how-do-i-access-the-outer-class-when-im-not-in-the-inner-class)

*Edit*: I'd like to reemphasize that the `this$0` approach is undocumented and might be compiler dependent. Thus please don't rely on that in production or critical code.

Comment: I am sure that you've noted here I am also out of the outer class!

Comment: @QiangLi that shouldn't matter, the method that retrieves the outer instance in the question I linked just happens to be in the outer class but doesn't have to be.

Comment: OK. Can you then complete the example to access the outer class instance from within the method `A.foo`?

Comment: @QiangLi what about trying it yourself? Basically just copy the method you find in the accepted answer of that link.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to see if `t` is an inner class of `B`:

```
public static void foo(Thread t) {
    System.out.println(t.getClass().getName().contains("B$"));
    // OR
    System.out.println(t.getClass().getEnclosingClass().equals(B.class));
}
```