# Why is calling a method (non-static) of the outer class with an object of an inner class not allowed outside the definition of the outer class?

Tags: java, inner-classes, non-static

We know that objects of inner classes can only arise from objects of the enclosing class. So then why is it the case that an object of a inner class cannot invoke a non-static method of an enclosing class outside the definition of the enclosing class?

```
public class OuterClass
{       
public class InnerClass
    {
        public void innerMethodA()
        {
            outerMethodA(); // This is OK.
            new InnerClass().outerMethodA(); // This is not OK.
        }
    }

    public void outerMethodA()
    {
        System.out.println("This is OuterMethodA");
    }
}

public class ExtraClass 
{
    public void testMethod()
    {
        OuterClass outerObj = new OuterClass();

        OuterClass.InnerClass innerObj = outerObj.new InnerClass();

        outerObj.outerMethodA();  // This is OK.
        innerObj.outerMethodA();  // This is not. Why is that?
    }
}
```

Please excuse any mistakes in formatting or the way I am putting forward my question. I edited it after some down votes. I tried my best. Thank you.

Comment: I think this needs code.  I'm not really sure what you mean.

Comment: You need an instance of any class to call it's non-static methods. Inner classes don't magically have that instance just because it's enclosed

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this? What is the driving force behind this question? In what situation would this make sense?

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but I *think* in both cases it is simply that `outerMethod` is not a member of `InnerClass`.

Comment: @Tom: It is not a duplicate. That question only talks about calling a an outer class method from within the inner class definition.

Comment: `InnerClass` does not have a method `outerMethodA`. So you cannot call `outerMethodA` on an instance of `InnerClass`.

Comment: This is what I am reading in Absolute Java by Savitch " to create an object of the inner class, you must start with object of the outer class. This has to be true, because an object of the inner class may
invoke a method of the outer class or reference an instance variable of the outer class "

Comment: Right-o.  See my answer for an example how to do this.

Comment: This is in the 5th ed. Am I understanding something incorrectly. Why is it then that I cannot invoke a method of the outer class?

Comment: "may" = "may chose to."  May does not mean "can automatically do so without declaring any extra methods."

Comment: Also, there is a difference between the inner class itself, and all other classes such as `ExtraClass`.  Notice I have to use the inner class to allow `ExtraClass` to access the outer method.

Answer (score 1):

Per this stack overflow question, it isn't possible (in practice) to get an enclosing class from an inner class.

[get the enclosing class object from anonymous inner class as function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9024882/get-the-enclosing-class-object-from-anonymous-inner-class-as-function-parameter)

The only solution I see is to provide a method on `InnerClass` which makes the call for you.

```
class OuterClass
{

   public class InnerClass
   {
      public void innerMethodA()
      {
         outerMethodA(); // This is OK.
         enclosingInstanceMethodA(); // This is OK now.
      }

      public void enclosingInstanceMethodA()
      {
         OuterClass.this.outerMethodA();
      }
   }

   public void outerMethodA()
   {
      System.out.println( "This is OuterMethodA" );
   }
}

class ExtraClass
{

   public void testMethod()
   {
      OuterClass outerObj = new OuterClass();
      OuterClass.InnerClass innerObj = outerObj.new InnerClass();
      outerObj.outerMethodA();  // This is OK.
      innerObj.enclosingInstanceMethodA();  // This is OK now.
   }
}
```