# Can I modify the value of a field for testing purposes?

Tags: java, reflection, singleton, junit4, java-7

I'm having trouble changing the value of a field for testing purposes.

Despite the issues around singletons I want to use it for my log files manager. I actually gave it a thought if I should rework my design but was happily [approved](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/co-single/index.html#h4) that my decision was probably OK.

I want to test it though. Especially if the code is run on windows and linux and maybe somewhere else I can't think of right now.

The idea is to create a testing directory in the current directory called "testlogs", delete it and play with it. So I can be sure I have write privileges at least in the current directory or I can inform the user that no log files will be written or I can prompt him to select another place etc.

In the following code I keep getting my "logs" directory. I would like to be able to spare the real "logs" (if they exist).

Why can't I change the value of `dirname` ?

```
package com.home.app.logger.LogsMngr;
public class LogsMngr {
    private static class Holder {
        public static String dirname = "logs";
        public static final LogsMngr INSTANCE = new LogsMngr(dirname);
    }

    private LogsMngr(String dirname){
         createDirectory(dirname);
    }

    private createDirectory(String dirname) {
         // logic to create a directory on the filesystem
    }

    public static LogsMngr getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }
}


@RunWith(SeparateClassLoaderRunner.class)
public class Test {

    LogsMngr lmngr;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        try {
            // Remove existing directory
            TUtils.rmfDirectory("testlogs");

            // Set directory name
            String className = "com.home.app.logger.LogsMngr$Holder";
            Class[] memberClasses = LogsMngr.class.getDeclaredClasses();

            Field dirnamefield = null;

            for(int i=0; i<memberClasses.length; i++) {

                if(memberClasses[i].getName().equals(className)) {

                    dirnamefield = memberClasses[i].getField("dirname");
                }
            }
            //TODO catch NullPointerException because of dirname?

            // To prevent from IllegalAccessException:
            dirnamefield.setAccessible(true);

            // Set test directory
            dirnamefield.set(null, "testlogs");

            // Create
            lmngr = LogsMngr.getInstance();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

References:

[SeparateClassLoaderRunner.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102/using-different-classloaders-for-different-junit-tests)

[Java language docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html)

[What's the proper way to test a class with private methods using JUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/whats-the-proper-way-to-test-a-class-with-private-methods-using-junit)

[Can I discover a Java class' declared inner classes using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471749/can-i-discover-a-java-class-declared-inner-classes-using-reflection)

[The_solution_of_Bill_Pugh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#The_solution_of_Bill_Pugh)

**Solution:**

```
package com.home.app.logger.LogsMngr;
public class LogsMngr {
    private static String dirname = "logs"; <-- moved out of Holder

    private static class Holder {
        public static final LogsMngr INSTANCE = new LogsMngr(dirname);
    }

    private LogsMngr(String dirname){
         createDirectory(dirname);
    }

    private createDirectory(String dirname) {
         // logic to create a directory on the filesystem
    }

    public static LogsMngr getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }
}


@RunWith(SeparateClassLoaderRunner.class)
public class Test {

    LogsMngr lmngr;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        try {
            // Remove existing directory
            TUtils.rmfDirectory("testlogs");

            Field dirnamefield = LogsMngr.class.getDeclaredField("dirname");

            // To prevent from IllegalAccessException:
            dirnamefield.setAccessible(true);

            // Set test directory
            dirnamefield.set(null, "testlogs");

            // Create
            lmngr = LogsMngr.getInstance();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
Class[] memberClasses = LogsMngr.class.getDeclaredClasses();
```

will cause `LogsMngr.Holder` to be initialized, causing the `INSTANCE` field to also be initialized, so changing `dirname` at any time after that will have no effect.

To do what you're trying to accomplish, you'd have to be able to set the `dirname` field without first initializing the class containing it, which I believe is impossible in Java, though I'd be interested to be corrected on that point. However, I believe you can get the effect you're looking for by simply moving `dirname` out of `Holder` and into `LogsMngr`. Then simply set `LogsMngr.dirname` to whatever value you want before using `LogsMngr.Holder` for anything.

Comment: why is the static field not changeable after initialization, it is not marked `final`?

Comment: It's changeable, but your singleton is created on initialization, so any changes after that won't have any effect.